# How to prevent Entity Framework Core adding additional left join?

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core

My Entity Framework Core 6 query joins two tables (parent/child) but when I use child table in select clause to build a DTO property, Entity Framework adds a second (LEFT) join to child table. How do I restructure my query to fix this? I'm using SQLite.

Parent entity class:

```
[Table("Route")]
public partial class Route
{
    public Route()
    {
        Stops = new HashSet<Stop>();
    }

    [Key]
    [Column("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    /// Some properties

    [InverseProperty("Route")]
    public virtual ICollection<Stop> Stops { get; set; }
}
```

Child entity class:

```
[Table("Stop")]
public partial class Stop
{
    [Key]
    [Column("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    /// Some properties

    [Column("RouteId")]
    public int? RouteId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("RouteId")]
    [InverseProperty("Stops")]
    public virtual Route Route { get; set; }
}
```

Query:

```
var routeToSend = await (from r in context.Routes
                         join s in context.Stops
                                on r.Id equals s.RouteId
                         where r.SendToServer == true
                         select new RouteDto
                                    {
                                        ...,
                                        Stops = r.Stops.Select(s => new StopClassDto
                                                        {
                                                             ...
                                                        }).ToList()
                                    }
                        ).ToListAsync();
```

Resulting SQL query:

```
SELECT some columns
FROM "Route" AS "r"
INNER JOIN "Stop" AS "s" ON "r"."id" = "s"."RouteId"
LEFT JOIN "Stop" AS "s0" ON "r"."id" = "s0"."RouteId"
WHERE "r"."sendToServer"
ORDER BY "r"."id", "s"."id"
```

The left join to `Stop`, caused by the `Stops = r.Stops...` in my Entity Framework query is what causes the problem.

Comment: select stops using the `s` you joined earlier instead of r..Stops -- `select new RouteDto { Stops = s.Select(stop => new StopClassDto { ... })`

Comment: Thanks for the response however that won't work because `s` is a single stop not a list/enumerable so no Select method exists on it. Any other ideas?

Comment: Oh then you can probably just completely remove the explicit join in the LINQ query -- `join s in context.Stops on r.Id equals s.RouteId`

Comment: Good thought but that removes the inner join to `stops` and leaves me with a single left join to `stops` which returns extra data.